# Amazon S3 Infrequent Access and RPO

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If we have a requirement on 24 hours max for RPO on data stored in Amazon S3, would S3IA be able to satisfy that?

Yes, you can say it could because Amazon S3 data is automatically replicated to 3 AZs in the region, so having a 24 hrs max RPO can ba handled. But what if disaster happens in the entire region?

Would we need a cross region replicate to satisfy this RPO requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Part of your business's recovery objective goals should include identifying what type of outages are worth spending the money to guard against. Do you want to protect your business from a temporary regional AWS outage? Do you want to protect your business from a huge natural disaster that permanently destroys an entire AWS region? Do you want to protect your business from some sort of social or political upheaval that causes AWS to be shutdown in an entire country? Your business has to evaluate the level of outage that they anticipate to be an actual threat, as well as the level of outage that is worth the investment of capital to guard against.

I'm saying all this to explain why asking random strangers on the Internet if you need to implement cross region replication makes no sense. Only your business can answer that question, and simply staging an RPO number does not provide enough information.

---

Cross region replication, not only to a different region but also to an S3 bucket in a different account, is always a good idea. This gives you protection not only from an AWS regional outage, but also from your AWS account being hacked. Depending on what sort of outages you want to guard against, you may want that bucket to be in a different country, or even in a different hemisphere.